# Class not found in library project using reflection

Tags: java, android, classnotfoundexception

I'm adding a library project(.aar) file into DemoProject where library project internally uses reflection.

But DemoProject shows `classNotFound`for the reflection classes.

Stacktrace.

```
Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.coderconsole.phoneUtils
 at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
 at java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:781)
 at java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:841)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:504)

 Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the boot class loader; no stack trace available
```

Code:

```
try {
            return Class.forName("com.coderconsole.phoneUtils");
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

The exception is thrown when using within libraryproject else its working fine.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: There might be few reasons for the problem:

 1. Library might really not have this class
 2. You may be using wrong ClassLoader
 3. You might added dependarcy incorrectly
 4. Library aar might be obfuscated with ProGuard, which renames classes.

Comment: @VladMatvienko Thanks 1. Its present I have crossed check 3. Dependency is correct since other classes are working fine 4. Library is in debug mode. Your point '2' is something interesting. How would I know the correct ClassLoader?

Comment: well, you can try using `Class.forName("com.coderconsole.phoneUtils", SomeYourClass.class.getClassLoader());`. i'm not sure it will work, but you could try at least.

Comment: Vlad Matvienko The thing is in normal project its work but it fails in library project. although the above too don;t work